# Select first and last occurrence of repeated colums in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this,

Date is in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
Name       Date          Credits 
--------------------------------
Bill      2013-04-04       5
Paul      2013-04-05       4
Bill      2013-04-05       3
Angel     2013-04-07       9
Bill      2013-05-01       8
Paul      2013-05-02       7
Bill      2013-06-15       6
Angel     2013-07-22       15
Paul      2013-07-23       7
Angel     2013-08-11       9
```

And my expected result is

```
Name       MinDate      MaxDate        Credits
-----------------------------------------------
Bill      2013-04-04    2013-06-15       1      
Paul      2013-04-05    2013-07-23       3
Angel     2013-04-07    2013-08-11       0
```

How to form the Query. Help needed.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Hint: Just write out your expected result columns as SQL and group by name, order by date, then you will almost be there. Not sure about how you get your credits value, but you could use an aggregate function too, if it doesn't matter.

Comment: How do you calculate credits?  Nothing obvious comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be something like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, MIN(t1.date) AS MinDate, MAX(t1.date) AS MaxDate
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.name
```

I don't know how you calculate your credits, though, so I left this one out.
If it's SUM(t1.credit) or something alike, just add this to the FROM-clause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One Quick Question. How can i get the actual credit point at specified date. For instance, if MaxDate is 2013-06-15 then CreditAtMaxDate -> 6 (refer table)

Comment: For that you need to write a sub-query:
SELECT t1.name, MIN..., MAX..., (SELECT t2.date FROM table t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name and t2.date = MAX(t1.date)) FROM table t1 GROUP..